# How decline a offer o call in peerjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, peerjs

hello guys How I can reject o accepted a call or offer is coming from the sender peer, I just using Peerjs client and peer server

this is my sender client

```
const peer = new Peer('sender', { host: '1.0.0.99', port: 9000, path: '/' })
var call = document.getElementById('call');
call.addEventListener('click',startChat);


    function startChat(){
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true}).then((localStream) =>{
        document.querySelector('video#local').srcObject = localStream;
        var call = peer.call('receiver',localStream);
        call.on('stream',remoteStream => {
            document.querySelector('video#remote').srcObject = remoteStream
        })
      })
    }
```

this is my receiver

```
const peer = new Peer('receiver', { host: '1.0.0.99', port: 9000, path: '/' })


peer.on('call', call => {
    const startChat = async () => {
        const localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: true
        })
        document.querySelector('video#local').srcObject = localStream
        // call.answer(localStream)
        call.close(mediaStream);
        call.on('stream', remoteStream => {
            document.querySelector('video#remote').srcObject = remoteStream
        })
    }
    startChat();
})
```

my goal on receiver can decline and accepted sorry I am new in this, thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

According to the oficial documentation, the [MediaConnection API](https://peerjs.com/docs.html#dataconnection), states that the `close()` method should be used to reject the call, and the `answer()` method to accept it. In your code, you have tried both, even though you're passing an argument to the `close()` function, which doesn't take any. Now if you close the Media Connection, I assume that the callback on the the 'stream' message is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

well I found the way

```
peer.on('call', call => {

    var acceptsCall = confirm("Videocall incoming, do you want to accept it ?");

    if (acceptsCall) {
        const startChat = async () => {
            const localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                video: true
            })
            document.querySelector('video#local').srcObject = localStream
            call.answer(localStream)
            call.on('stream', remoteStream => {
                document.querySelector('video#remote').srcObject = remoteStream
            });

            // Handle when the call finishes
            call.on('close', function () {
                alert("The videocall has finished");
            });
        }
        startChat();
    } else {
        alert('call decline!');
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the solutions I found was to start a conversation and after 0.1 seconds, close the connection, it is not one of the best solutions, but it was the one that served me the most.